# How important is it to match brands with wireless networking equipment?

Tags: wireless-networking, compatibility

Back in the day, when wireless in your home was new and exotic, I often heard it said that it was a crapshoot to try and use equipment from different brands on the same network.

Is that still true? (was it ever?)

I've got a Linksys (pre-Cisco buyout) wireless router and am looking at a D-Link Wireless PCI card for my desktop, but that old voice in the back of my head is warning against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignacio has a point that I want to elaborate:

It's only important to have equipment from the same manufacturer if you're using nonstandard network, meaning "pre-N" before the "N" standard was properly standardized, or (since you mention older gear) meaning "pre-G" before "G" was standardized.

So to your question *was it ever*, it's a clear yes. But *is that still true*: no, not anymore.

**These days, if you're using B/G networks then don't worry about this. If you're using N networks then check that none of the equipment is labeled "pre-N".**

Answer (score 2):

Only if it says "Pre-N" on it. 802.11n is now fully standardized.

Comment: Does draft-N mean the same as pre-N @Ignacio ?

Comment: @Sathya: Yes, it can be considered to mean the same thing.